# Is there a DateTimeFormatter for unix epoch milliseconds?

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

Is it possible to construct a `java.time.DateFormatter` such that the following are equivalent?

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(System.currentTimeMillis());
assert instant.equals(Instant.now);
String str = String.valueOf(instant.toEpochMilli());

Instant instant = Instant.from(formatter.parse(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())));
assert instant.equals(Instant.now);
String str = formatter.format(instant);
```

It seems a shame to have to special-case for when your text input is using epoch millis.

Comment: There is no `ChronoField` for the number of millis since the epoch. There is `INSTANT_SECOND` but not `INSTANT_MILLIS`.

Comment: Why do you want a date time formatter for this?

Comment: Because an API that takes a `String` and a `DateFormatter` is nicer than an API that takes a `String` and a `DateFormatter`, or a `String` or maybe a `Number`, and a `TemporalUnit`, or maybe assumes that integers, decimals and doubles are epoch seconds, while longs and bigintegers are epoch millis, and the caller has to parse the string first.

Comment: And again in the other direction.

Comment: Why not just make an API that takes an `Instant` and let the caller worry about it?

Comment: Because then the caller (who is also me) will come here to ask this question, to make their `String` -> `Instant` and `Instant` -> `String` code nicer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you know that your dates are reasonably recent (the number of seconds since the epoch is more than 1), you can use this formatter:

```
new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendValue(ChronoField.INSTANT_SECONDS, 1, 19, SignStyle.NEVER)
        .appendValue(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 3)
        .toFormatter();
```

Otherwise, it gets a bit tricky and you are probably better off parsing the long value directly:

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(Long.parseLong(millisString))
System.out.println(instant.toEpochMilli());
```

Comment: Nice trick. Side-note: this can parse well up to year `316889355` so I guess we're fine :).